# Connect Visual Studio Code Python debugger with rpdb2

Tags: python-3.x, vscode-debugger

I want to debug a [Sigrok protocol decoder plugin](https://sigrok.org/wiki/Protocol_decoder_HOWTO) from Visual Studio Code. There is a [Visual Studio Code plug-in](https://donjayamanne.github.io/pythonVSCodeDocs/docs/debugging_remote-debugging/) for remote debugging. But this doesn't connect to the rpdb2.

Unfortunately these two debug engines use different approaches that they can't connect each other. Using PTVSD doesn't work in the sigrok environment. If you add this to your decoder script

```
import ptvsd
ptvsd.enable_attach()
```

you get a trace back

Traceback (most recent call last):

> File "/home/harper/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ptvsd/_vendored/pydevd/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_comm.py", line 283, in _on_run
>      self.process_net_command_json(self.global_debugger_holder.global_dbg, json_contents)
>
> File "/home/harper/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ptvsd/_vendored/pydevd/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_process_net_command_json.py", line 164, in process_net_command_json
>      cmd = on_request(py_db, request)
>
> File "/home/harper/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ptvsd/_vendored/pydevd/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_process_net_command_json.py", line 314, in on_attach_request
>
> return self._handle_launch_or_attach_request(py_db, request, start_reason='attach')
>
> File "/home/harper/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ptvsd/_vendored/pydevd/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_process_net_command_json.py", line 297, in _handle_launch_or_attach_request
>      self._send_process_event(py_db, start_reason)
>
> File "/home/harper/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ptvsd/_vendored/pydevd/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_process_net_command_json.py", line 278, in _send_process_event
>
> ```
> if len(sys.argv) > 0:
> ```
>
> AttributeError: module 'sys' has no attribute 'argv'

- Is there any way to connect these two debug engines?
- How can I use PTSVD in an environment like sigrok-cli?
- How can I connect rpdb2 from Visual Studio Code?

*Edit:* It might be possible to use another IDE or a different debugger. The question is intentionally about using VS Code.

Comment: Have you tried debugging it locally first? If I understand the architecture correctly, sigrok runs on your pc, to which the device it receives signals from is connected?

Comment: Debugging locally is unfortunately not possible because the sigrok development is done on Linux. Therefore I use WSL to setup the Ubuntu.exe as a host for the debuggee.

Comment: How about using pdb from within ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

`ptvsd` as mentioned in the source you provided is deprecated, but there is an alternative: `debugpy`: https://github.com/microsoft/debugpy/

My steps to be able to debug a sigrok decode python file:

1. Install `Python Debugger` VSCode extension
2. Install `Python` VSCode extension
3. Create `launch.json` file in the `.vscode` folder with the following content:

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Debug Sigrok decode",
            "type": "debugpy",
            "request": "attach",
            "connect": {
                "host": "localhost",
                "port": 5678
              }
        }
    ]
}
```

4. In the `pd.py` file import debugpy: `import debugpy`
5. Add the debugpy listen command into the **init**() function of your decoder class:

```py
debugpy.listen(("localhost", 5678))
# Optional
# debugpy.wait_for_client()  # blocks execution until client is attached
```

6. Set a breakpoint after the listen command
7. Launch configuration in VSCode